# Exclamation mark in css is inverted

Tags: html, css

```
p:before { content:"\00a1"; }
```

But this is inverted exclamation mark. I just need normal exclamation mark. Any ideas folks?

Comment: How did you end with this if you wanted an exclamation mark ?

Comment: Why would you want a normal exclamation mark at the *start* of something (which is what `:before` suggests)? The inverted exclamation mark “¡” makes sense at the start of an exclamation in some languages.

Answer (score 7):

No need for an unicode code if you want a standard character :

```
p:before { content:"!"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Below classes are the Exclamation Mark with round red background

.dot {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dot:before {
    content:'\0021';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

\00a1 is the unicode for an inverted exclamation mark, just use content: '!'; because ! isn't *really* a 'specia

Answer (score 0):

`\0021` is the unicode for 'normal' exclamation mark. Your code will look like:

`p:before { content:"\0021"; }`